# Is * in a mysql query slower than picking specific columns?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I'm trying to figure out if:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_mine
```

is slower than:

```
SELECT this_column,that_column FROM tbl_mine
```

in my MySQL queries.  Can anyone speak to this based on experience?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's slower because the database has to send more data back to the client, but unless the data you're selecting is substantial this delay (on a simple query like you've provided) should be negligible. In other words, if you have a table with three fields, `SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM table` is the same as `SELECT * FROM table`.

Comment: It depends how far you're sending it and also the number of returned rows.

Comment: Ok that makes sense.  Now: What if my only reason is to check for an existance of a row, and I LIMIT 1 as well?

Comment: In that case, I think `SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table WHERE id = whatever` is your best bet. You can `LIMIT 1` if you want, but if `id` is your primary key I see no reason why you'd get any performance gain.

Comment: @Jimmy.  Hmm...  I was under the impression that without `LIMIT 1`, every row in the table would be searched no matter what.  With this though, it stops when it finds the first one, meaning it will definitely take less time... is that not correct?

Comment: @Shackrock. If ID is your table's primary key, MySQL is smart enough to do and index lookup on that value, and not go through the entire table (limit or not). This is another reason the `select * from table` can be slower. If you have an index which covers all the columns used in the query (select & where clauses), MySQL can go through the index, and not touch the main table. Indexes are smaller and therefore faster to read.

Answer (score 3):

Ignoring any specific index-driven optimisations (which may very well make a huge difference, but that's a wider discussion), the query itself won't take any non-trivial extra time.

You may experience slight slowdowns with the increased amount of data being sent through buffers and whatnot. You may *certainly* experience even significant slowdowns if you're then sending this data (especially if it's a lot) over a network connection or between applications.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a table with say 20 fields, and your only wanting say 5 of them, it is good practice to call the fields, and not to select all.

As already stated, if your database has gotten big, then selecting all will/may decrease the speed of the site over time, as the  user base grows.